# PHP - File_get_contents not working on remote server

Tags: php, apache, nginx, remote-server

file_get_content isn't working on my remote server that is running php 5.6.

I made a test script just calling 
file_get_contents('https://google.com') and its giving me the following error:

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 319144 bytes) in FILE_PATH on line 14

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024m');

//$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
//$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(file_get_contents("https://google.com"));
echo "</pre>";
echo "test";

//$w = stream_get_wrappers();
//echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
//echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
//echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
//echo 'wrappers: ', var_export($w);

 ?>
```

I've googled and most solutions were too change the value of

allow_url_fopen to 1/on or to increase the memory limit, I've done both to no avail.

Additionally, if I add headers it works but it didn't need it before.

Any help would be much apperciated.

Additionally, its running: 
nginx/1.6.2 
Apache/2.2.22

Comment: What is exactly at line 14?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: You are reaching memory limit. And I don't think content of `httos://google.com` can be so big. Maybe post code around line 14?

Comment: line 14 is file_get_contents('https://google.com')

Comment: You're crossing 1GB of used memory. I doubt `file_get_contents` downloads 1GB from Google.

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop or long-running script or something? A single `file_get_contents` call should not cause this.

Comment: @deceze no, its a simple script where the only call is file_get_contents because its causing an issue else where in my code, so I wanted to isolate this issue

Comment: @D.Dimitrov posted

Comment: That is… very weird. Please provide as much information about that specific PHP installation as possible.

Comment: @deceze added to the end of post.